# Ubuntu 16.04 DVD Playback

Tags: 16.04, video, dvd, playback

I am currently setting up a kodi PVR which is all finished apart from DVD playback.

I have ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop which I set up about a year ago and the dvds play fine on there. When I set this up I did this which has always worked.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libdvd-pkg
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

I have repeated these steps on my PVR (even did a clean install with and without updates) and I can only play non-encrypted DVDs. (None of the ones I have purchased legally work)!

What has changed and how can I get it to work?

I installed windows 10 and libdvdcss for windows on the same hardware (both computers) and all my DVDs play fine (the ones I had time to try anyway). But I don't want to use windows! Everything else works in ubuntu just not DVDs!

I have tried two dvd drives and same problem on both (both work on my desktop PC)

Answer (score 0):

**For 14.04 (and possibly others but IDK)**

Run the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
$ sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

After they finishes executing, encrypted DVDs should work right away, but if they don't, try rebooting.  This worked perfectly for me - before I did it, encrypted DVDs would crash the Videos program and give an error report.  After, they play flawlessly.

**For 16.04**

[Reference](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/10/play-dvds-in-ubuntu-16-04/)

Enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg -y
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

After that you should be able to play encrypted DVDs (reboot may be necessary)

Comment: Hi, As I said in OP I already had livdvdread4 installed. The script you said to run does not exist. A little search suggests it does not get included in ubuntu 16.04 any more which is why I tried libdvd-pkg (with no success). All that happens is the dvd spins up then there is a black screen (in VLC and ubuntu videos app) and then the disc stops. If I put in a non-protected DVD it plays fine

Comment: Oh okay I wasn't aware that that was removed from 16.04 - I use 14.04

Comment: I edited the answer to include a method for 16.04 - I can't test it because I don't use 16.04, but I got it from a reliable source

Comment: I have just set up a fresh VM of ubuntu 16.04. All I have done us install updates upgrade and dist-upgrade. When it has finished I will snapshot and try the 16.04 method and post back

Comment: OK I tried as you suggested and followed that guide exactly. No luck at all. VLC says for 3 different encrypted DVDs DVDRead could not read -1/0 blocks at 0xbb

Comment: I just noticed that the first person to commend on that guide you sent said it does not work on 16.04 2 months ago!

Comment: aw man thats too bad sorry I couldn't help you :(

Comment: That's OK thanks for the suggestions. It is a real shame there is no official documentation on this topic. I can understand why they cannot give you the functionality out of the box (licensing etc) but I cannot understand why there is not an  option in ubuntu that you can select which then goes online and gets the libdvdcss packages and sets it all up for you. I mean it used to work fine but it is getting ridiculously more and more involved every ubuntu release.

Comment: I just downloaded the iso clean installed 14.04.5 and run the two commands you had for 14.04 then rebooted and I have the same error as 16.04. Videos app says An Error occurred The film could not be read. I have just tried 6 DVDs from 2003 to 2016 and none work. Again, non-copy protected DVDs work fine. I also just made a copy of a protected DVD and the copy plays but not the original. Argh! What is going on :(